# Python xlrd Parsing issues

Tags: python, parsing, xlrd

I am trying to read an .xls file.  I am getting the following when I try and open it with XLRD.  The sheet opens fine in Excel......but I am unable to find much on this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./art.py", line 7, in <module>
  workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("/opt/zir/data/input/May2020executions.xls")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 88, in open_workbook_xls ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 632, in biff2_8_load
cd = compdoc.CompDoc(self.filestr, logfile=self.logfile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 90, in __init__
raise CompDocError('Expected "little-endian" marker, found %r' % mem[28:30])

xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'
```

Any help would be great.  I'm lost here.  If I load it into Excel, and save it is .xlsx, it works fine.....but I thought XLRD reads .xls file......

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you read the .xlsx file back into Excel, and save that file as a new .xls file, are you able to read the resulting file without the error?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure how to do this.   Do you have any examples, or pages I can look at?   Never considered this.

Comment: Just an experiment to see if the original .xls is badly formatted as far as the xlrd module is concerned, but Excel is more forgiving when it reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlrd

file_path = r'test.xlsx'


def read_file():
    table = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = table.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    print(table.sheet_names())
    print(sheet.ncols)
    print(sheet.nrows)
    print(sheet.cell(1, 0).value)
    for row in range(0, sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(0, sheet.ncols):
            print(sheet.cell(row, col).value, end='------')
        print('')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_file()
```

You can try this.

Comment: Thanks.  But when I run this script, I get the same error as:   Expected "little-endian" marker, found b'\xff\xfe'.     So, still a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely must use XLRD, the alternative is to read the file in Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

workbook = pd.read_excel("/opt/zir/data/input/May2020executions.xls")
```